# Why is the pointer no longer referencing the memory it was assigned?

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to programming and I am watching a tutorial on pointers to understand how they work. In the tutorial, the instructor stated the following:

> The for-loop assigns values to the address of pointer p. Then the address stored in pointer p is incremented at line 21 to the next integer chunk. This approach works but what happens to pointer p? Its reference is gone. After the for-loop, pointer p no longer references the allocated chunk of memory.

the instructor proceeds to the next lesson without explaining how the reference is gone. Can someone explain how the pointer is no longer referencing the memory it was assigned?

P.S. This is my first time using StackOverflow. Tips on how to correctly ask questions would be appreciated if I posted this one incorrectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *p,x;

    /* allocate storage */
    p = (int *)malloc( sizeof(int) * 10 );
    if( p==NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Allocation failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* fill storage */
    for( x=0; x<10; x++ )
    {
        *p = x * 100;
        /* reference the next integer location */
        p++;
    }
    puts("Memory allocated and filled");

    return(0);
}
```

Disclaimer: This code does not belong to me. I do not take credit for it.

Comment: What do you think happens with `p++`? It's modifying the pointer itself, making it point somewhere else. The original value of `p` (and the value returned by `malloc`) is lost.

Comment: Phrasing it a little differently: Lets say you have `int a; a = 0; a++;`. I don't think anyone would argue that `a` still keeps its original value. It's the same with pointers.

Comment: My current understanding from Barmar's response is that p is only holding 1 address. I initially thought the malloc command allowed p to hold the address of 10 integers and the for-loop was assigning those addresses with integer values.

Comment: You could recreate the original pointer with `p - 10`. It would be considered bad coding though.

Comment: Just took a better look at the quoted text from your tutorial. That is a very imprecise text. I can only infer its meaning because I already understand pointers. Burn that book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After it calls `malloc()`, `p` points to the beginning of the `int` array that was allocated.

During the loop, it uses `p++` to make it point to the next element of the array. At the end of the loop, it points to the address just past the last value in the array. So it no longer points to the beginning of the array.

If you want to do anything more with the array, such as print the contents, return it to a caller, or free it, you need the original pointer to the beginning of the allocated memory. So you need another variable that isn't updated during the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *p,x,*original_p;

    /* allocate storage */
    p = (int *)malloc( sizeof(int) * 10 );
    original_p = p;
    if( p==NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Allocation failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* fill storage */
    for( x=0; x<10; x++ )
    {
        *p = x * 100;
        /* reference the next integer location */
        p++;
    }
    puts("Memory allocated and filled");
    free(original_p);
    return(0);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use array indexing rather than incrementing the pointer:

```
    for( x=0; x<10; x++ )
    {
        p[x] = x * 100;
    }
```

Comment: In the original code, after the for loop would p hold the address of the last value?

Comment: it holds the address just after the last value, since we increment `p` after assigning the value.

Comment: Ok I think I understand it now. I thought p was able to hold 10 addresses and the for-loop was filling up those addresses with values

Comment: A pointer just points to one location in memory. That's why we increment it, to make it point to the location of the next integer in the memory that was allocated.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now. Also, thank you for the sample code you provided. It helped me understand what was going on much better

Answer (score 1):

At the start of each `for` loop iteration, `p` points to somewhere in memory; that location gets assigned a value, and then `p` is changed so it no longer points to that location.

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop the pointer `p` is incremented 10 times.

```
for( x=0; x<10; x++ )
{
    *p = x * 100;
    /* reference the next integer location */
    p++;  // <===
}
```

So after the for loop it does not point to the allocated memory because the memory was allocated exactly for 10 elements. That is now the pointer `p` points to beyond the allocated array.

Answer (score 1):

What he's talking about is that once the pointer is incremented the block of memory allocated can't be freed because it no longer points to `p[0]`. Keep in mind that `int *p` and `p[0]` mean the same thing in this example. So he's essentially asking "how do we free p now that we've lost track of it?". Too bad he didn't expand on that before he moved on because it would have made more sense to you.

The simplest thing to do would just be to make another that you can use to move around in the array with then go back to the original pointer when you are done with it. Like this:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
int *cp = p; /* current location */
```

Then move `cp` around as you see fit, incrementing, decrementing, etc. And when you are done with `cp` you `free(p)`

Answer (score 1):

Let's think abut creating a string, by hand.  As you may know, a string in C is just an array of characters, terminated by a special "null" character.  Here's a very simple example, which I encourage you to experiment with:

```
char string1[10];
char *p = string1;
*p++ = 'a';
*p++ = 'b';
*p++ = 'c';
*p = '\0';                 /* this is the special "null character" terminator */
printf("%s\n", string1);   /* prints "abc" */
```

In this example, the pointer `p` steps along the first few cells of the array `string1`, filling in characters.  Then, we print out the string we've just constructed.

Here is a second example of almost the same thing, except that we call `malloc` to obtain some dynamically-allocated memory to construct the string, rather than using an array:

```
char *string2 = malloc(10);
if(string2 == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "out of memory!\n"); exit(1); }
char *p = string2;
*p++ = 'a';
*p++ = 'b';
*p++ = 'c';
*p = '\0';
printf("%s\n", string2);
```

This second example works almost exactly the same way the first one does, and it also prints "abc".

Now, finally, here is a third example.  Pay attention to the differences.

```
char *p = malloc(10);
if(p == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "out of memory!\n"); exit(1); }
*p++ = 'a';
*p++ = 'b';
*p++ = 'c';
*p = '\0';
/* but now how can we print the string? */
```

In the second example, the pointer `string2` still pointed at the beginning of the allocated region, which was the beginning of the string we constructed, so it was possible to print it.  In this third example, we have no record of that pointer, so we have no direct way to print the string.

Theoretically, since we know how many characters we placed in the string, we could cheat, and print it like this:

```
printf("%s\n", p - 3);       /* DANGEROUS */
```

But this is a silly and dangerous thing to do.  Normally, the thing to do is keep one pointer pointing to the beginning of the string, and use another to step along it -- that is, as we did in the second exampe, with `string2`.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `p` itself is only a *pointer* to some memory. It can't point to ten things at once, only one single thing.

And what is pointing at (initially!) is the first element of the "array" that you've allocated with `malloc`. After doing `p++` once, then `p` is pointing to the second element, and so on.

Somewhat graphically it's like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^
  |
+---+
| p |
+---+
```

This is directly after the call to `malloc`. The number are the indexes of the elements.

Now if we do `p++` once it will look like this instead:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      ^
      |
    +---+
    | p |
    +---+
```

Then after a second `p++`:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
          ^
          |
        +---+
        | p |
        +---+
```

And so on...